# How do I delete a custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm really stuck at this one problem. I have a UICollectionView that uses a custom cell (cells are added after user's button press)

Every cell has a button alongside with a few other unrelated controls. When that button is tapped, I want the cell to be deleted.

This is my current problem order:

- User taps a button beneath UICollectionView to enter the ViewController editMode
- User taps a cell and the selected cell enters it's own editMode (not VC editMode)
- User for some reason taps on another cell and gets reminded that only 1 cell is editable at a time
- user presses "ok" and decides to delete the first selected cell by pressing a button subview inside cell A.
- because the user tapped cell B before tapping delete on cell A, the indexPathsForSelectedItems is set to cell B instead of Cell A, causing the user to unfortunately delete the wrong cell.

**Deletion code:**

```
- (void)deleteProjects:(NSNotification *)notification {
// Get the current project
NSString *currentProject = [[MyManager sharedManager] projectForDeletion];

[_objects removeObject:currentProject];

[_projectsCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

    NSArray *selectedItemsIndexPaths = [_projectsCollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

    // Now delete the items from the collection view.
    [_projectsCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:selectedItemsIndexPaths];

} completion:nil];

// Set deleteAlert to NO as we're pretty much done with deleting
deleteAlert = NO;

// Set editedProjects to 0
editedProjects = 0;

// Set deletedProject
deletedProject = currentProject;

// Save the new objects
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_objects forKey:@"myProjects"];

// Delete the associated subjects if any
[self deleteAssociatedSubjects];

// HERE
[_projectsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

**Select code:**

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Get the tapped cell
ProjectCell *projectCell = (ProjectCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (editMode == YES) {
    if (editedProjects == 0) {
        // Set deleteAlert to YES so that we don't mix this UIAlertView
        // with the create project UIAlertView
        deleteAlert = YES;

        // Set editMode to YES for the selected cell
        [projectCell editProject];

        // Prepare the project cell
        projectCell.projectTextField.text = projectCell.projectLabel.text;

        // Set the firstProjectsViewController to YES
        // indicating that the next tapped cell will be second in line
        // in case the user decides to edit a new cell without closing this

        // Set editedProjects to 1
        editedProjects = 1;
    } else if (editedProjects == 1) {
        // Check if the tapped cell is being edited
        if (projectCell.editMode == YES) {
            // Set deleteAlert to YES so that we don't mix this UIAlertView
            // with the create project UIAlertView
            deleteAlert = YES;

            // Set editMode to YES for the selected cell
            [projectCell editProject];

            // Set editedProjects to 0
            editedProjects = 0;

            // Close the keyboard
            [self.view endEditing:YES];

            // Set editedProjects to 0 as we're closing editMode on this cell
            editedProjects = 0;

        } else if (projectCell.editMode == NO) {
            // Tell the user that only 1 project is editable at a time
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can only edit 1" message:@"You can only edit 1 project at a time" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
            [alert show];
        }
    }
} else {
    // Set the open project
    MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
    sharedManager.openProject = nil;
    sharedManager.openProject = @"";
    sharedManager.openProject = _objects[indexPath.item];

    // Open the selected project and dismiss this ViewController
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
}
```

**Button IBAction (cell code):**

```
- (IBAction)deleteProjectAction:(id)sender {

// Set the projectForDeletion in MyManager
MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
sharedManager.projectForDeletion = _projectLabel.text;

// Leave editMode so that we're ready for a new project cell if desired
[self editProject];

// Programatically select this cell
self.selected = YES;

// Tell the ProjectsViewController to delete the project
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"deleteProject" object:self];
}
```

**In short: how do I delete a custom UICollectionViewCell easily?**

I can't describe my happiness and gratitude for help!

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Use `collectionView:shouldDeselectItemAtIndexPath:` to prevent the user from being able to deselect an item that is currently in editing mode (and by not allowing multiple selection the tapped item should never be selected, though you can also use `collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:`).

Comment: That's exactly what I thought of to, could please, please show how I would implement this in my code? I'll upload @Wain

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by backing up the NSIndexPath when I wanted to and then deleting that. Like this:

didSelectItemAtIndexPath:

```
    // Set the cellForDeletionIndexPath so that it won't change even though another cell is tapped
    cellForDeletionIndexPath = indexPath;
```

Deletion code called by a notification sent from cell class (button)

```
    [_projectsCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

    // Now delete the items from the collection view.
    [_projectsCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:cellForDeletionIndexPath]];

} completion:nil];
```